# jQuery hide() function doesn't work with an alert box

Tags: jquery, ajax

I've got a problem with the jQuery hide method during an ajax call.
When the ajax method starts, the loader div is properly shown but in the success (or error) method the loader div is hidden only after the alert box is closed.

```
$.ajax({
type: 'GET',
url: 'ajax/myfile.php',
dataType: 'json',
data: {'id':id, 'message':message},
beforeSend: function() {
  // Show image container
  $("#loader").show();
},  
success: function(result, textStatus, jqXHR) {
  $("#loader").hide();
  alert(result.message);
},  
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  $("#loader").hide();
  //Display the error.
  alert(textStatus+': '+errorThrown);
}
```

What can I do to make the loader div hidden right away ?

Comment: As stated in the [official documentation](https://api.jquery.com/hide/) `.hide()` takes an optional `complete` handler that gets executed after an element from the collection has been hidden. Call `alert()` in that handler.

Comment: `alert` immediately interrupts and blocks your UI (ie before hide() can update the DOM, which occurs when your js stops running) - don't use `alert` for *anything* other than basic debugging (and then use `console.log` so it doesn't block).  Use another method to notify issues, such as toastr

Comment: @Andreas The "handler solution" works but unfortunately the variable I need is out of scope. Is there a way to pass an external variable to the handler ?

Comment: Why should it be out of scope? The handler is in the same scope as the `alert()` was.

Comment: I need the "result" variable (see my code above) but what I've tried so far doesn't work  
`$("#loader").hide('slow', function(result) {alert(result.message);});`  
I get "undefined" in the alert box.

Comment: @Duddy67 You're creating a new function argument called `result` which only exists within the function scope.

Comment: @BadHorsie So there is no possibility to retrieve the `result` variable within the handler ?

Comment: @Duddy67 Instead of `function (result) {` you just need `function () {` so you don't overwrite the `result` variable with your own argument in the function scope.

Comment: _"I need the "result" variable (see my code above)"_ - Which was not the case in the initial version of your question! Just don't define a `result` parameter for the event handler. `.hide(function() { alert(result.message) })`

Comment: _"Which was not the case in the initial version of your question!"_ Indeed, I made a typo, sorry for that. That works thanks.